# smbclient protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT not supported SMB dialect?

Tags: smb, smbclient

I'm trying to do some enumeration on the kioptrix vm from vulnhub and failing to list available shares using `smbclient`. According to nmap tcp/139 is open. I've used metasploits auxiliary smb_version module and it looks like the Samba version is 2.2.1a. When I try to connect `smbclient -L //x.x.x.x` I get the error **protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT**.

So I connected back with Wireshark running and it looks like that smbclient is not advertising the particular dialect (2.2.1a) if i understand correctly, hence the connection is not established.

[image]

In this post https://www.reddit.com/r/oscp/comments/fg956k/kali2020_htb_smbclient_protocol_negotiation/ it was recommended to add NT1 (smb version 1) as the minimum supported version but that's not how you would enumerate a target. Are there any reasons why the particular dialect would not be included in smbclient or am I simply wrrong here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kali Linux, edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add the following under `global`:

```
client min protocol = CORE
client max protocol = SMB3
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, helped me!